# Saga:processing resample extent in python editor QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga, resampling

I would like to resample many geotiff layers to another geotiff layer's extent and pixel size. For this I would like to use the QGIS python console (editor). When I run my script it raises the following error:

File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/parameters.py", line 165, in setValue
    tokens = text.split(',')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

When I run the saga resampling from the processing toolbox

```
enter code here

import processing
input    ="/Users/rutgerhofste/GitHub/AlgeriaTest01/Data/Raster/CHIRPSMewina/CHIRPSMewinaY2012M01.tif"
keep_type = True
target = 0
scale_up_method =  0
scale_down_method = 0 

user_xmin = -17.0999999594
user_xmax = 35.7000007799
user_ymin = 14.6999995737
user_ymax = 37.

output_extent = [user_xmin,user_xmax,user_ymin,user_ymax]


user_size = 0.050000
user_grid = "/Users/rutgerhofste/Desktop/werkmap/testgrid.tif"

processing.runalg('saga:resampling', input, keep_type, target, scale_up_method, scale_down_method, output_extent, user_size, user_grid)
```

When I run the algorithm from the processing toolbox everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

The Saga:processing python function demands extent to be a string "-17.0999999594,35.7000007799,14.6999995737,37.0" 
rather than a list or tuple.